# Is there a word for extended form of "lol" ("lolololol...")?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the Esperanto word for *lololololol*?

In Esperanto, the word for *lol* is *mdr* (*multe da ridoj*).

In many languages, there is also an extended form of internet slang for expressing laughter, with a repeating part denoting its intensity, analogous to the English *lolololol*, where one may add another *~ol* and it would still be a word. Here are some examples:

- In Chinese, it is *23333333* or *hhhhhhhh*
- In Japanese, it is *wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww*
- In Korean, it is *ㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋ*

Since in esperanto, one may use multiple of the same pre/affixes to denote more intensity (*finfine*, *mulmulte*), it seems one reasonable candidate to express a more intense laughter would be *mmmmmmmmmmmmdr*.

However, a quick google search revealed no Esperanto sources uses this word, which prompted me to ask this question. What‘s the word for *lololololol*? Or is there one?

Comment: *Hahahaha* or *hehehehe* are certain to be understood, but *hhhhhhh* is possible, and your own suggestion of *mmmmdr* seems okay to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a word for extended form of “lol” (“lolololol…”)?

**No.**

Is there one specific word for an extended form of "lol"? I am not aware of one. Is it "lolol", "lololol", "lolololol" or something else?

If you feel the need to extend *something*, go with "haha" which you can extend with however many ha's as you want.

Anything other than a modification of "mdr" or "haha" is not very likely to be understood by a general audience.

Comment: Can one do "hahahahahaha" in Esperanto?

Comment: Yes, one can certainly do that in Esperanto.

Comment: @Zuoanqh: Ne, vi ne povas... hahahaha! ;-)

Comment: I'm picking this answer because this is the most straight-forward and well explained. Thanks also to @Hugo for his insight.

Answer (score 5):

In French, *mdr* is also an equivalent to *lol* (it stands for *mort de rire*, meaning "dead of laughter"), and a lot of time, people use *mdrrrr* (with more or fewer r's), so maybe it could also be used that way in Esperanto?

Comment: Bam! That's a precedent right there, already using the same expression in French. Mojose!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a word for extended form of “lol” (“lolololol…”)?

**No.**

Esperanto isn't for replacing every English word ever invented. It's for expressing ideas. What is the idea expressed by "lololololol" (expressed in real words)? Write that in Esperanto. There's your answer to "What is the Esperanto word for lololololol?"

Since it's not clear to me what idea you're trying to express with "lololololol" (different from "*mi ridas*" or "*tio estas amuza*"), I'll leave this last step as an exercise for the asker.

Comment: `In many languages, there is also an extended form of internet slang for expressing laughter, with a repeating part denoting its intensity`

Comment: I don't think that clarifies the matter.

Comment: Do you understand what 'lol' expresses? 'lolololol' would just be a more emphasized, exaggerated version of it, simple as that. It's true that Esperanto isn't for replacing every English word ever invented (although as the asker said, these stronger versions of (equivalents of) 'lol' exist in other languages as well), but that doesn't mean any specific word might not have an Esperanto equivalent. Just that it needs not.

Anyway, I wouldn't know what this would be in Esperanto either. Probably there is no direct equivalent. But most people who understand mdr probably would understand mmmmmdr.

Comment: "LOL" means different things to different people. There was a time, for example, when it was only used in *reaction* to something someone else said. Now it seems to mean "I think I'm funny" or "please don't be angry". And yes, I understand that the more o's and l's on the end, the more "exaggerated" it is. My point is that people should focus on expressing themselves clearly in Esperanto. What are you trying to say? How do you say it clearly? Questions of the form "What is the Esperanto word for X" are almost always ill-formed because there's no reason to assume that X is expressed by 1 word.

Comment: This is not the usual "what's the word for X" kind of question, in my opinion. If I understand correctly, the OP is searching for a way to emphasize the Esperanto _mdr_, similar to how it's done in English with _lol_. There will most likely be a way to emphasize this expression, no matter how its meaning may or may not change with time. It's not so much about word meanings, but more about internet expressions, which applies to any language, including Esperanto.

Comment: This is exactly my point. Just because lol can become lololol, there's no reason to think that one can or should "emphasize mdr". Just figure out what you want to say, and figure out how to say it clearly. Words exist for a reason - and the best way to express that something is really funny in Esperanto is with ... words.

Comment: To me this is not about how to express something, but how to visually emphasize something, which you could do like _THIS_, like _**this**_ or like _thiiisss_. It so happens that people use _lololol_ in English and _mdrrrr_ in French for emphasis, and they are perfectly understood by others. It works in any language and it's used regularly in chats and text messaging, where those shortcuts may well come in handy. I'm not saying it's fine to write like that in formal writing.

Comment: I don't see the value in arguing over what a third party meant. He can clarify if needed.

Comment: @Vidamuzo I think you get what my point is. I would like to add that, words are not defined by dictionaries, but by how they are used -- and dictionaries explain that. One good example is how the "hello" at the beginning of a phone call -- it is not sufficient to translate what it meant: In no language, afaik, one starts a phone call with "are you there and do you hear me?". They all have short, easy words for this purpose. *That's what this question is asking*. It's completely fine to say "Nah we don't have a word for it". But whether such a word should exist is out of scope.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Sure, but the question was not "What is the Esperanto word for X", but "Is there an Esperanto word for X", which I don't think has the same problem. The answer might well be, "Not exactly, but here is how I would say it [in such and such a context]". I think the question, therefore, is fine, and not ill-formed. Even if a question does say "What is the Esperanto word for X", I would just implicitly understand it to mean "How might one express X in Esperanto". (Sorry for this comment added so much after the fact, but I came across this again by chance.)

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: LOL is an English slang abbreviation, thus you can't really translate it.

**Long answer**: According to Merriam-Webster and Collins dictionaries *LOL* is an English abbreviation for *laugh/laughing out loud*. Oxford Dictionaries goes a bit further giving examples of its informal use as an exclamation (*LOL!*) and a verb (*I literally LOL'd when the updates popped up, I was LOLing at the teeny tiny little sign*). Wikipedia defines it as an internet slang acronym, which is a kind of abbreviation. In Esperanto you can either use it unchanged (which many do in other non-English languages) or you could make an abbreviation from the translation of its idea: *multe da ridoj* or *morta de rido* = *mdr* (in [Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallongigoj_uzataj_en_babilejo) it appears with uppercase: MDR).

I don't think there are rules for denoting the intensity of *mdr* like you do in English with *LOL*. I think you can use it as you like, as long as others understand it. :-)))